# Can I configure Chrome to tolerate weak Diffie Hellman keys?

Tags: chromium

I'm at an airport (read: captive portal) and Chrome on my laptop refuses to visit the guest portal because the server has been configured to use https only but has not been configured to use a strong DH key.

I'm getting this error, specifically: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/err_ssl_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key

Where is the option for "I accept the risk"?

Chromium 44.0.2403.107

Comment: I'm aware of logjam, and will promptly put the setting back as soon as I am able.

Comment: Use a different browser.